# Who are the most senior users here?

Tags: discussion, election

As moderator election is underway, I'm interested to know who is the most senior user here in Christianity.SE, who knows about the site from the beginning.  It might be useful in deciding which candidates to vote. I can't find a way to sort the users according to their joining date.

Comment: What do you mean by "most senior"?

Comment: Not the age of the person, of course. How long the user had been here.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think that seniority is a particularly good criteria for our votes. I would much rather see the votes go to people who actively participate in the site, rather than those whose only qualification is that they have been around for a while.

I say this because some of those who were instrumental in launching the site are no longer particularly active participants. For example, even if [the guy](http://marksinthesand.com/2013/06/19/founder-christianity/) who [proposed the site on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/8526/kramii) were standing for election, he wouldn't get my vote. Arguably the most senior of our users, he was clearly passionate about the direction of the site back in the early days. Nevertheless, his involvement dropped off rapidly, and he appears to have little time for the site these days. As a result, I've no reason to believe he has any real understanding of the site as it is *today*, so I couldn't support him.

No, it is far better to vote for someone who has demonstrated their passion for the site by their active involvement, and whose actions shows us that they understand the site's *current* purpose and direction. Such a person is far better qualified to moderate this site, and to help it become an increasingly valuable and lasting resource for those who have an interest in Christianity.

Comment: We do owe you a debt of thanks for proposing this site though.

Answer (score 6):

There are [68 of us](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta) that all got our start at the same time when the private beta phase launched. That lasted for a couple of weeks, then it became a public beta.

I don't think there is any way to qualify seniority per se. In order to participate in the private beta phase one needed to have made a commitment on the Area 51 proposal prior to launch, so all the private beta folks were involved before the first question got asked. Obviously participation levels varied widely from non starters and dropouts to some of today's most active participants.

Answer (score 5):

One measure of seniority is the lowest user ID who is not an SE employee and is still active.

In that case your oldest members who are still actively posting/commenting would be

- Peter Turner (user ID 4)
- aceinthehole (user ID 5)
- flimzy (user ID 20)
- Caleb (user ID 30)
- software monkey (User ID 32)
- norabora (User ID 38)
- Kramii (User ID 46)
- wax eagle (User ID 49)
- el'endia starman (User ID 58)
- Wikis (User ID 62)
- Andrew (User ID 65)
- Mason Wheeler (User ID 68)
- warren (User ID 69)
- C. Ross (User ID 80)
- RolandiXor (User ID 81)
- Benjol (User ID 83)
- Richard (User ID 84)
- daviesgeek (User ID 95)

I'll be the first to confess that my end point is arbitrary here (I checked the first 100, which doesn't even cover the first day of private beta) and that my criteria for "active" is rather subjective. Several users not on this list visit regularly, but do not have any main site activity in the recent past.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Here it is  http://data.stackexchange.com/christianity%20stack%20exchange/query/124566/top-x-oldest-users?Top=500

Answer (score 0):

<s>I'll go ahead and submit my own Data Explorer query. [This one] sorts the 97 users with more than 1001 rep by creation date.</s>

The old link is pointing to a different query, so here's [another one](http://data.stackexchange.com/christianity%20stack%20exchange/query/edit/124670) that I found.